# reset OS on NOOBS multiboot

Tags: multiboot

I have 3 operating systems on 3 different partitions on 1 SD, one of them is not working properly. 
How do I factory reset/reinstall one of them?

```
1) Raspbian
2) OSMC
3) Retropie
```

I logged in as root user on (1) raspbian found the (3) retropie root folder and erased/replaced the files with the files from a clean install. But I got a lot of errors.

```
Device          Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1           2048    253906    251859  123M  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         253907 124735487 124481581 59.4G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5         253952    319485     65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6         319488    483325    163838   80M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7         483328  16867327  16384000  7.8G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p8       16869376  17004543    135168   66M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p9       17006592  33390591  16384000  7.8G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p10      33392640  33509375    116736   57M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p11      33511424 124735487  91224064 43.5G 83 Linux
```

So I want a clean install on /dev/mmcblk0p11 how can I do this?

Comment: The `/dev/mmcblk0p11` is the root partition/filesystem and `/dev/mmcblk0p10` is it's boot partition/filesystem. I would guess that both would have to be installed/updated together. I would suggest to use another sd card, download and install on that card, boot it up, verify that it runs, boot up your original  sd card and copy both both boot and root of the new Retropie to your original sd card.

Comment: First of all I would personally use my Macbook and Disk Utility/Terminal to do this. Secondly I suggest not to use NOOBS because alot of issues can arise from that and it also takes up ≈ 3GB of extra space.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use NOOBs but instead use different SD cards where you plain install the different OS you want to use. Then you don't have to fiddle with the uggly NOOBS issues NOOBs users report all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is not possible.

I don't use NOOBS, but have used [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md), which is an enhanced NOOBS.

The following from the PINN site addresses the issue, and may help with NOOBS

https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md#how-to-customise-an-os-install-noobsconfig